# how to forward firebase analytics data to other trackers

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Firebase seems to create a google tag for each web app that i create inside a firebase project. This tag works perfectly fine and sends all my custom events via [`logEvent()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=web) to google analytics.

Now i would like to add other trackers, such as linkedin insight or meta pixel.

How do i do that? Obviously I can just add the tracking code to my html and then call specifig log functions for each tracker, but the purpose of google tag is to avoid exactly this, no?
But at the same time it seems i cannot "connect" these destinations to my existing tag. I can only add new tags, which I then also need to add to my app.

What's the best option to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing up GTM, gtag and firebase sdk.

You didn't indicate whether your app is native, but firebase is mostly used in native apps. And in apps that end up native after building, like react native.

Gtag and GTM are used in the world where you can execute arbitrary JS without the need to rebuild the app. Which might be your case since you've indicated html. In that case, you need to install GTM, not gtag, then reimplement your tracking in GTM, remove gtag and then you can add tags to GTM, including any third party pixels to your GTM and they will fire without the need for you to rebuild the webapps.

Now, true. There is GTM for native apps, but its functionality is extremely slim. It has no way to run custom code, it has very few variables available and the only way for it to send pixels is just through a pre-hardcoded endpoint. It's generally considered not worth it.

Most popular pixels have their own SDKs for conversion tracking. You can always make your custom functionality to send data to their endpoints, instead of using their SDK if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! I am talking about web only, yes. I somehow thought GTM and gtag are the same, so i was confused... 
But I still don't fully understand: Is GTM still just some JS that runs in my webapp, but then sends all the events to GTM server from where I can then add multiple tags, each of which sends the data to some destination (eg analytics, meta, linkedin,...)? And then again, could one of the destinations even be fb conversion api? If so, that's basically server side tracking then? I feel like i'm still missing sth....

Comment: No, you can try reading this: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager But gtag is a simple small lib whole idea of which is sending given events to an endpoint. GTM is a huge tool capable of dynamically loading libraries like gtag whenever needed. GTM is not a data destination, it's more of a router with an extensive nice UI for user-defined tracking logic. Once the users defined the logic to fire such and such event on so and so page, they have to publish the changes, which builds it into a bunch of JS that streamlines the events directly from your pages to the destinations.

Comment: One of the destination could definitely be just normal FB pixels. You could also do the FB conversion API from there, but it would have to be fired from your customers browsers, you don't want that. Also, there's server-side GTM, that still doesn't quite function as you described. It's not a real data destination, it's still a router, but now a router for http requests rather than user actions and such. What you described with the sources and destinations would be a CDP, which is a much more complex concept. And yes, normally CDPs support things like offline conversion API of FB and others.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, thank you very much! It seems setting up GTM is more time consuming than I expected after all, so I guess I will just add the trackers i need manually to my website, even though it feels messy to have so many scripts on my page, it seems easier for now...

Comment: Yes, it may be easier if you need just a tiny bit of tracking and that's it. I'd say it's the best use case for using gtag.